# Checking string value of variable in switch case using c#

Tags: c#, switch-statement

i am checking that variable username contain "ali" which is string value in switch case but my teacher told me earlier that you can only check data-type char and int but it is working fine with string so i am confused that checking string data-type in switch is good practice or not?

```
string userName = "Ali";//the variable i want to check

switch(userName)
{
  case "Ali"://value i want to check
  Console.WriteLine("found");
  break;

  default:
  Console.WriteLine("not found");
  break;

}
```

Comment: It's not clear what the question is. As you noted, you can use a string in a switch statement in C#.

Comment: Time to find a new school. FWIW, you can't do that in C or C++. Maybe your instructor has mixed up his/her languages.

Comment: my question is i am checking that variable username contain "ali" which is string value in switch case but my teacher told me earlier that you can only check data-type char and int but it is working fine with string so i am confused that checking string data-type in switch is good  practice or not?

Comment: Yes, nothing wrong with this technically although you don't have the control over culture or case sensitivity as you would if comparing two strings directly. Maybe your instructor is suggesting you should be using constants but still they're wrong to suggest it cannot be done. Ask them to clarify.

Comment: tomorrow is my paper and i am worried if she going to entertain my point or not by the way thanks all of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most certainly can use a string in a switch expression.

In C# 6.0 you could use integral values, enums, booleans, chars and yes, strings. Since C# 7.0 you can use any non-null expression. See [the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch) for additional details.

Comment: thanks i checked they also use the string value.
respect from  my side.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it. But not the way you try to do. Your string in switch is in uppercase but variable isn't. Also your variable named *userNAme* but in switch you try to use *userName*. Try this code:

```
string userName = "Ali";

switch(userName.ToLower()) 
{
    case "ali":
        Console.WriteLine("found");
        break;
    default:
        Console.WriteLine("not found");
        break;
}
```

Comment: yes you are right when i typed it i forget it thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use flow control switch for the string

```cs
but you find two error in your coding, because c# case sensitive

string userNAme and and you write switch(userName)
```

and

```
break: change to break;
```

Comment: yes i know case sensitivity i just typed demo code to ask my code